# Merge into multiple table using two different SELECT clause from a WITH statement (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ddl

I have a procedure refreshed daily, I want to insert / or merge into 2 table from a single source, but I don't want to create one then `delete and insert data` to a table just only for the source (`T1 table`) (I don't use that source table for reporting and it have many rows so the procedure might run slowly)

My desired result is:

> Merge into or insert into 2 existing tables using

> with `t1` table

> and `two select query` from that t1 table (the two select query have different purpose, one is `map the detail` (supposed group by ID) and one is `group by month`,... etc from t1 table)

From what I have researched so far, `insert all`  only support single query and insert to multiple table, and `merge into` only merge into 1 table with 1 single query.

How to combine these?

Comment: As you already noticed, you cannot `merge` into two different targets. You may perform two separate `merge` statements, possibly with `forall` PL/SQL statement if you have some heavy calculations. You may also improve the performance by executing these statements in parallel using `dbms_parallel_execute`. Please describe what is your current issue and what is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @astentx Please send example of `forall` in `merge`